# Equality test on a shared array without stopping pool multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I am using the `multiprocessing` python library and can use it to parallelize an inner loop on a shared array. 
I  am using Python3 and a Linux computer with multiple CPUs.

This inner loop has to be repeated a certain number of times until this array stop changing.

What I am doing is stopping the pool to perform the comparison with the last state of the shared array then restart the pool if the array has changed. 
I imagine there is a cost to constantly stop and restart the pool. It works but is there a way to do it more efficiently ?
(`list_of_args` is not changing at all)

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
shared_arr = mp.Array("i", np.arange(N), lock=False)
#Can only be performed if the pool is stopped
current_state = np.array(shared_arr)
def init_globals(array_args):
    global shared_arr
    shared_arr = array_args

while True:
        # Starting the pool
        with Pool(initializer=init_globals, initargs=(shared_arr,)) as pool:
            pool.starmap(f, list_of_args)
        # Exiting context manager therefore stopping the pool
        next_state = np.array(sharred_ar)
        if np.array_equal(next_state, current_state):
            break
        else:
            current_state = next_state
```

Probably in an efficient code `with Pool` could be placed out of the while loop. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Perhaps you could keep an auxiliary of size N(threads) that tracks if a give thread made a change in a given iteration. Whenever no changes are made, you could break.

Comment: Could you expand on your answer ? I need to monitor the changes after pool.starmap has finished.